# Can I add Short Code Of A Plugin In The Code Editor of WordPress?

Tags: plugins, shortcode, widgets

I'm an amateur in WordPress, so need much needed help.

Can I add the short code of a plugin in the code editor of WordPress, will it work?

I need to make some buttons in the frontpage log into a web3 wallet. The plugin short code helps me to do that.

I have a Neve theme. I tried using the plugin widget but was not successful.

Please do advice to resolve. Thanking you and very grateful.

[image]

Comment: By code editor are you referring to this? https://wordpress.org/support/article/appearance-editor-screen/

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I'm not sure. I will attach a screenshot of my screen above.

Comment: Yes, you can use shortcodes in the visual/code editor of Wordpress. What kind of buttons do you want on your frontpage? There will be easier ways to get them there

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I was thinking of using the same buttons that are there on the WordPress theme in the frontpage. I was thinking of replacing the url with my short code. Does this work? Do let me know. Thank you.